# Função JS que Valida Email para IE e Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo um codigo em JS que valida email perfeitamente e está em uso no portal. No então essa função não funciona no navegador IE e/ou Edge.

```
function validaEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```

```js
function validaEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return regex.test(email);
}

console.log(validaEmail("Danielle.com"));
console.log(validaEmail("danielle@arruda.com"));
```

Comment: Abri essa página com o Edge e IE e funcionam

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo , obrigada pelo comentário. Após sua postagem, tive a ideia de colocar essa funciton dentro do mesmo arquivo JS e não somente referencia-la como estava fazendo. Sim... Não sei o motivo, mas funcionou. Quando eu separo essa função e coloco em outro arquivo e referencio, funciona em todos os demais navegadores menos no IE. Quando colocado no mesmo arquivo ai o IE consegue enxergar. Obrigada

Comment: Não entendi, chamando ou não no arquivo js funciona da mesma forma tanto no IE quanto no Edge. Veja, todo o código no arquivo js http://kithomepage.com/sos/danielle.html e a chamada na pagina que chama o js http://kithomepage.com/sos/danielle2.html

Comment: você colocou as funções, agora coloque o código da forma que você valida o formulário para analisarmos.